# Disabling a constructor using std::enable_if

Tags: c++, constructor, stdstring, enable-if

My aim is to create my own analogue of `std::basic_string` but with some additional conditions. I want my `AnyString<CharType, Traits>` to be convertible from `std::basic_string<CharType, AnyOtherTraits, AnyAlloc>` but I want to disable this constructor for some CharType such that `basic_string<CharType>` does not exist (compile).

I tried to do something like that:

```
    template<typename OtherTraits, typename Alloc, typename = 
        std::enable_if_t<!std::is_array_v<char_type> && 
        std::is_trivial_v<char_type>                 && 
        std::is_standard_layout_v<char_type>>>
    AnyString(const std::basic_string<char_type, OtherTraits, Alloc>&);
```

And I have `ColouredChar`, which does not meet the conditions listed inside `enable_if_t`.

Now, when I'm trying to call the disabled constructor :

```
std::basic_string<ColouredChar> de("string"_purple);
ColouredString d(de);
```

I do not only get the compile errors from `basic_string` but also very strange one, telling me that completely different PRIVATE constructor constructor cannot convert its parameter from `basic_string`.

Is there any way to make these compile errors more readable? Or at least explain whether there's anything here to worry about.

Comment: You might try to make use of concepts, which typically produce more grokkable diagnostics; however this is too broad, and vague, for a concise answer.

Comment: I regarded concepts, but I have no idea of how to apply them here.

Comment: actually your requirement is strange, you create `std::basic_string<ColouredChar> de("string"_purple);` so it exists, but you think it doesn't exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basic example for constructor restriction using concepts (not your traits)

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <string>

// declare your own concept
template<typename type_t>
concept my_concept = std::is_convertible_v<type_t, std::string>; // just a demo concept
    
class ColouredString
{
public:
    // then you can limit your constructor to types satisfying that concept
    ColouredString(const my_concept auto& /*arg*/)
    {
    }

    ~ColouredString() = default;
};


int main()
{
    // ColouredString str{ 1 };
    ColouredString str{ "hello world!" };

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

just to point out, in addition to exist answer, you don't need to define a concept to use it in require-clause

```
class ColouredString{
public:
    template<typename T>
    requires (std::is_convertible_v<T, std::string>)
    ColouredString(const T&){}
};
```

---

and there is already a [`std::convertable_to`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/convertible_to) concept

```
class ColouredString{
public:
    ColouredString(const std::convertible_to<std::string> auto&){}
};
```

---

---

fwiw, since you said

> I want to disable this constructor for some CharType such that basic_string does not exist

your code fail with `string` constructor probably simply because you try to create one. it has nothing with `ColouredString`

```
std::basic_string<ColouredChar> de("string"_purple); // it already fail here
ColouredString d(de);
```

Comment: You're right. We cannot initialize a ColouredString without creating a `std::basic_string` via the described constructor. `std::basic_string` itself generates compile errors when we trying to create it. But the problem was unreadability of compile error texts - that's what I asked about. Thank you.

Comment: @CapyMaths it's not like constraint on `ColouredString`'s constructor would help then.